# Flat List - ScrollToIndex should be used in conjunction with getItemLayout or onScrollToIndexFailed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
setTimeout(() => { this.myFlatList.scrollToIndex({animated:true , index: 100}) }, 100);
```

[image]

If i use scrolltoindex in flat list return to me this error;

> scrollToIndex should be used in conjunction with getItemLayout or
>   onScrollToIndexFailed

I tried to use  getItemLayout but my flatlist items have different height, how can i fix this?

```
getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
                {length: 40, offset: 40 * index, index}
              )}
```

Comment: increasing the timeout solved my problem. Have you found any other solution? Plz post.

Answer (score 75):

I had a similar error with a horizontal list showing images where the selected image should be shown in a carousel when pressed.

I solved it by setting the selected index on the `FlatList` by using `initialScrollIndex`. I also used `onScrollToIndexFailed` to scroll to the correct image for the times when `initialScrollIndex` failed to show the correct image.

This is done by setting a timeout for 500ms and then scroll to the selected image.

Complete example (with only the props regarding this error):

```
const flatList = useRef<FlatList>(null);

...

<FlatList
  ref={flatList}
  initialScrollIndex={props.activeIndex}  
  onScrollToIndexFailed={info => {
    const wait = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
    wait.then(() => {
      flatList.current?.scrollToIndex({ index: info.index, animated: true });
    });
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Fixed my problem. But can you explain why I am getting this error?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.Thanks.
@Kasra if it fails it runs the function in onScrollToIndexFailed which wait for 500 milliseconds then it tries again to scroll to the index that's it.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and solved it by changing `initialNumToRender` in `FlatList`.

This prop defines how many components to render. If you scroll to an index which has not been rendered, then the error will show.

React Native `initialNumToRender` default is **10**, I changed for `initialNumToRender={60}`. You need to change this number if your list is bigger or smaller.

Comment: not a general solution, as the number of items changes in a realtime chat application

Answer (score 6):

The proposed solution wasn't working in my case.

My understanding is that the `FlatList` lays out only a few next items in the list (`initialNumToRender`) and can scroll only to those items, but not beyond.

**If the list items all have same height**, I have another solution that works even on long lists. That is to scroll to a specific coordinates instead:

```js
export default MyComponent = props => {
  const flatListRef = useRef()

  return (
    <FlatList
      ref={flatListRef}
      ...
      onScrollToIndexFailed={({
        index,
        averageItemLength,
      }) => {
        // Layout doesn't know the exact location of the requested element.
        // Falling back to calculating the destination manually
        flatListRef.current?.scrollToOffset({
          offset: index * averageItemLength,
          animated: true,
        });
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the best solution for me was a combination of the above answers.

```js
onScrollToIndexFailed={({
  index,
}) => {
  flatListRef.current?.scrollToOffset({
    offset: index * 1000,
    animated: true,
  });
  const wait = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
  wait.then(() => {
    flatListRef.current?.scrollToIndex({ index, animated: true });
  });
}}
```

When scrolling to index fails,
1/ Scroll to offset to an overestimated offset position, basically the max value of height your items may have
2/ 500ms scrollToIndex

It ends up progressively scrolling to the right index with multiple onScrollToIndexFailed calls, until it succeeds thanks to scrolling to the bottom of the list with scrollToOffset.

It's not beautiful but it works.